# How to correctly use python type hinting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting, python-typing

I read in the docs that type hinting exists in Python as of version 3.5
I wrote two functions in an ipython terminal to test out what this means for the 'same' function.

```
def dostuff(name: str) -> str:
  print(str.capitalize())

def do_stuff(name):
  print(str.capitalize())
```

calling `dostuff('arthur')` and `do_stuff('arthur')` both return 'Arthur', as expected.

however, calling `do_stuff([])` and `dostuff([])` also both return the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'capitalize'
```

This makes sense, the same error is in both, and it's valid, but why doesn't the type hinter/checker actually declaratively state `argument not of type 'str'` or something?

Also, if you define something like:

```
def do_stuff(name: str) -> str: 
    return list(name)
```

even though the function should return a string, the interpreter doesn't even complain that I am returning a list and not a string.

I know these are contrived examples, but am I doing something wrong?

Comment: CPython does not check type hints at runtime... use a typechecker like `mypy` to check your typing declarations.

Comment: Side-note: Your code doesn't match your description and your hints. Your arguments are named `name`, but the body of the function uses `str`. And you claim a return of `str` with the annotation, but use `print`, not `return`, so the actual return is `None`.

Answer (score 10):

No, you're not doing anything wrong.

Type hints were implemented in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), which stated with emphasis that **Python will remain a dynamically typed language, and the authors have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention.**

The purpose of type hints is to allow linters/IDEs etc. to flag possible type problems, not to provide additional runtime error info.